# How can i build a route in Pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid

I'm using `pyramid_handlers` for routing, `controller.py`:

```
import pyramid_handlers
from blue_yellow_app.controllers.base_controller import BaseController
from blue_yellow_app.services.albums_service import AlbumsService


class AlbumsController(BaseController):
    @pyramid_handlers.action(renderer='templates/albums/index.pt')
    def index(self):
        # data / service access
        all_albums = AlbumsService.get_albums()

        # return the model
        return {'albums': all_albums}
```

And I've registered in `__init__.py` like this:

```
from pyramid.config import Configurator
import blue_yellow_app.controllers.controller as albums


def main(_, **settings):
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    config.include('pyramid_chameleon')
    config.include('pyramid_handlers')

    config.add_handler(
        'albums' + 'ctrl_index', '/' + 'albums',
        handler=albums.AlbumsController, action='index')
    config.add_handler(
        'albums' + 'ctrl_index/', '/' + 'albums' + '/',
        handler=albums.AlbumsController, action='index')
    config.add_handler(
        'albums' + 'ctrl', '/' + 'albums' + '/{id}',
        handler=albums.AlbumsController)
```

Now how can I add new controller view for one certain album? I've tried
to add new view like this:

```
import pyramid_handlers
from blue_yellow_app.controllers.base_controller import BaseController
from blue_yellow_app.services.albums_service import AlbumsService


class AlbumsController(BaseController):
    @pyramid_handlers.action(renderer='templates/albums/index.pt')
    def index(self):
        # data / service access
        all_albums = AlbumsService.get_albums()

        # return the model
        return {'albums': all_albums}

    @pyramid_handlers.action(
        name='albums/{id}',
        renderer='templates/albums/item.pt')
    def album(self):
        print ('test')
        return {}
```

But it doesn't work. How to add view for rout `albums/{id}`?

Comment: `pyramid_handlers` package has not been updated for quite a while. Maybe if you edit the question as "How can I achieve X" in Pyramid we can give you a general response doing it without any external packages.

Comment: We might also want to bring in Michael Kennedy, as I recognize this source code from his courseware: https://github.com/mikeckennedy/python-for-entrepreneurs-course-demos/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=pyramid_handlers&type=Code

Comment: Mikko: Handlers hasn't been updated for some time. But I would this really is more a "it's done" situation more than the wrong way. When was the last time URL dispatch was significantly changed? I don't actually know, but I suspect it's nothing major in years either.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this code is from my [Python for Entrepreneurs course](https://talkpython.fm/launch). Let's focus on the add_handler section. The generic form of the function is:

```
 config.add_handler(NAME, URL, handler=HANDLER, action=OPTIONAL_ACTION_METHOD)
```

You want to map the URL `/albums/rock-classics` to the action method `def album(self)`. In the add_handler call you have:

```
config.add_handler(
    'albumsctrl', '/' + 'albums' + '/{id}',
    handler=albums.AlbumsController)
```

The problem is two-fold:

You do not specify the action either in the routing values or in the function call. You should have:

```
# via add_handler, url: /albums/rock-classics
config.add_handler(
     'albumsctrl', '/albums/{id}',
     handler=albums.AlbumsController, action=album)
```

or

```
# via route, url: /albums/album/rock-classics
config.add_handler(
     'albumsctrl', '/albums/{action}/{id}',
     handler=albums.AlbumsController)
```

Second problem is your name in the action method itself

```
 @pyramid_handlers.action(
     name='albums/{id}', <----- PROBLEM: this is not a valid action name
     renderer='templates/albums/item.pt')
 def album(self):
     print ('test')
     return {}
```

It should either duplicate name='album' or just be the name of the method as:

```
 @pyramid_handlers.action(renderer='templates/albums/item.pt')
 def album(self):
     print ('test')
     return {}
```